# How do I update my multiple line chart data in D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've picked apart a couple of different examples to get as far as I have. I have a simple two-line line chart being fed by an object. For testing, I created a function that increments the data by adding a new datapoint to the end. I would like my chart to reflect those additions.

What works:

- The data gets added to the object.
- When button clicked, YScale adjusts

What doesn't work:

- XScale doesn't adjust for new data.
- Team 1 line adapts Team2 line's data and then scales along the Y accordingly.

It's a mess. And Just when I think I understand D3, the data incorporation humbles me!

Here's some code and [a mostly-working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/johnlayne/6hac363m/6/).

UPDATED: Here's [an updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/johnlayne/6hac363m/7/) that has it working as expected. I know D3 makes a lot of this stuff easier so, while it works, I'm looking for a more graceful way to get the same outcome.

My data format...

```
//SET SAMPLE DATA
var data = [{
  "team": "Team 1",
  "score": 0,
  "elapsedTime": 0
}, {
  "team": "Team 1",
  "score": 2,
  "elapsedTime": 3
}, 
    ...
{
  "team": "Team 2",
  "score": 18,
  "elapsedTime": 60
}];
```

My update function...

```
function updateChart(){
    //SPLIT UPDATED DATA OBJECT INTO TWO TEAMS
    dataGroup = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) {
      return d.team;
    })
    .entries(data);

  //DRAW LINES
  dataGroup.forEach(function(d, i) {

    // Select the section we want to apply our changes to
    var vis = d3.select("#visualisation").transition();

    xScale.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
      return d.elapsedTime;
    })]);
    yScale.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
  return d.score;
    })]);

    //PROBLEM: Team 1 line changes to Team 2's data
    vis.select("#line_team1")  
      .duration(750)
      .attr("d", lineGen(d.values));
    });

    vis.select("#line_team2")
        .duration(750)
      .attr("d", lineGen(data));

    // X-SCALE NEVER ADJUSTS
    vis.select(".x.axis") // change the x axis
      .duration(750)
      .call(xAxis);

    // Y-AXIS SEEMS TO SCALE AS EXPECTED
    vis.select(".y.axis") // change the x axis
      .duration(750)
      .call(yAxis);
};
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Dear Layne, did my solution helped you?

Answer (score 1):

One way to further simplify your code is to change it to update *based on the data itself.*

A method that I often use is obtaining the selector for updating the data from the data itself. In your case you could use the `key` property of your `dataGroup` objects:

```
dataGroup.forEach(function(d, i) {
  vis.select("#line_"+d.key.toLowerCase().split(' ').join(''))
    .duration(750)
    .attr("d", lineGen(d.values));

  var maxi = d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return d.elapsedTime;
  });
  ...
});
```

Or you could do the preprocessing in your `d3.nest()` call in order to obtain the key in form of `team1` and use it as a selector.

Here's a fork of your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5h759u0u/) with working example.